# PyQt5: Error in sys.excepthook. I can't see the exception occuring

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread, sys

I am getting the following error when executing:

`Original exception was: Error in sys.excepthook:`

My code is a single file that looks like this:

```
_excepthook = sys.excepthook
def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    _excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
sys.excepthook = exception_hook

class Worker(QObject):
    global picture

    SNSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    RestartSignal = pyqtSignal()

    def FuncioSaveDB(self):

            while True:
                if Variable == True:
                    ... Some Code...
                    
                    try: 
                        cur.execute("") 
                    except mariadb.Error as e: 
                        print(f"Error: {e}")


                    info =  client.publish(
                            topic='inTopic',
                            payload=msg.encode('utf-8'),
                            qos=0,
                    )

                    info.wait_for_publish()
                    print(info.is_published())
                    picture = False
                    self.SNSignal.emit(SN)
                self.RestartSignal.emit()


class Ui_Dialog(object):


    def setupUi(self, Dialog):

        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(1014, 661)
        self.labelImage = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelImage.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(54, 125, 881, 471))
        self.labelImage.setText("")
        self.labelImage.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(""))
        self.labelImage.setScaledContents(True)
        self.labelImage.setObjectName("labelImage")
        self.labelSN = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelSN.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 80, 231, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.labelSN.setFont(font)
        self.labelSN.setObjectName("labelSN")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

        self.FuncioDB()
        self.FuncioMQTT()
        self.runWorker()
        
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.labelSN.setText(_translate("Dialog", "XXXXXXXXXXXX"))
    
    def runWorker(self):

    def SomeMoreFunctions():
    ...
```

As proposed solutions in some other similar questions. I added this code part and now my code is not interrumped by the exception but its constantly displayed in my console. Before adding that snipper of code The execution was interrumped by the execution. And the error message was:

```
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
Unhandled Python exception
```

I do not know how to fix this as I can't see what's the exception being raisen

Comment: Not sure if it'd help, but in this case my first step would be wrap everything in try/except, print the exception, and hope for the best.

Comment: @Peter I tried this and the outcome is the same. Constant prints in the console with Original exception was: Error in sys.excepthook:. Any ideas

Comment: Afraid not, my best suggestion would be to stop the function early or comment out code and see if you can pinpoint on which line the error occurs

Comment: If the worker is in a different thread, you should to trap **all** exceptions (not just `mariadb.Error`) and either print them directly, or send them as a string back to the main thread via a custom signal.